# combine two array with same key and multiple values

Tags: php, arrays

i have two arrays which having one same key value pair. I want to combine two array having same key value pair and rest of the array elements as multidimensional array.

Following are the arrays

Array 1

```
 $array1=Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [sequence_number] => 2541
                        [name] => Damodhara
                        [connection_date] => 2018-03-16 12:19:41
                        [comm_address] => 
                        [meter_no] => 34347
                        [connection_name] => DOMESTIC
                        [ward_name] => ALAPE
                        [corp_name] => Corp1
                        [agent_name] => agent
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [sequence_number] => 4568
                        [name] => Das
                        [connection_date] => 2018-03-15 13:38:49
                        [comm_address] => 
                        [meter_no] => 108
                        [connection_name] => DOMESTIC-FLAT
                        [ward_name] => ALAPE
                        [corp_name] => Corp1
                        [agent_name] => mcc
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [sequence_number] => 7890
                        [name] => Reghu
                        [connection_date] => 2018-03-17 11:18:32
                        [comm_address] => 
                        [meter_no] => 35345
                        [connection_name] => DOMESTIC
                        [ward_name] => ALAPE
                        [corp_name] => Corp1
                        [agent_name] => 
                    )

                [3] => Array
                    (
                        [sequence_number] => 12345
                        [name] => Abhay
                        [connection_date] => 2018-03-15 13:38:44
                        [comm_address] => 
                        [meter_no] => 666
                        [connection_name] => DOMESTIC
                        [ward_name] => ALAPE
                        [corp_name] => Corp1
                        [agent_name] => agent
                    )

            )
```

Array 2

```
        $array2=Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [sequence_number] => 4568
                    [date_of_reading] => 2018-03-16 09:25:38
                    [previous_billing_date] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
                    [previous_reading] => 1000
                    [current_reading] => 1200
                    [water_charge] => 100.00
                    [supervisor_charge] => 0.00
                    [penalty] => 0.00
                    [meter_status] => NOT LEGIBLE
                    [bill_no] => 1678
                    [arrears] => 0.00
                    [total_amount] => 100.00
                    [total_unit_used] => 890
                    [paid_amount] => 100
                    [payment_date] => 2018-02-26 00:00:00
                    [transaction_number] => 
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [sequence_number] => 4568
                    [date_of_reading] => 2018-03-16 09:25:38
                    [previous_billing_date] => 2018-02-12 00:00:00
                    [previous_reading] => 1000
                    [current_reading] => 1200
                    [water_charge] => 100.00
                    [supervisor_charge] => 0.00
                    [penalty] => 0.00
                    [meter_status] => MNR
                    [bill_no] => 1690
                    [arrears] => 0.00
                    [total_amount] => 250.00
                    [total_unit_used] => 0
                    [paid_amount] => 250
                    [payment_date] => 2018-03-05 00:00:00
                    [transaction_number] => 
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [sequence_number] => 12345
                    [date_of_reading] => 2018-03-15 12:43:58
                    [previous_billing_date] => 2018-02-13 00:00:00
                    [previous_reading] => 2000
                    [current_reading] => 2200
                    [water_charge] => 100.00
                    [supervisor_charge] => 0.00
                    [penalty] => 0.00
                    [meter_status] => NOT LEGIBLE
                    [bill_no] => 1777
                    [arrears] => 0.00
                    [total_amount] => 200.00
                    [total_unit_used] => 200
                    [paid_amount] => 
                    [payment_date] => 
                    [transaction_number] => 
                )


            [3] => Array
                (
                    [sequence_number] => 2541
                    [date_of_reading] => 2018-03-13 10:26:05
                    [previous_billing_date] => 2017-11-01 15:24:29
                    [previous_reading] => 10000
                    [current_reading] => 11000
                    [water_charge] => 0.00
                    [supervisor_charge] => 0.00
                    [penalty] => 0.00
                    [meter_status] => MNR
                    [bill_no] => 446986171123632
                    [arrears] => 0.00
                    [total_amount] => 0.00
                    [total_unit_used] => 1000
                    [paid_amount] => 0
                    [payment_date] => 2018-03-05 00:00:00
                    [transaction_number] => 
                )


            [4] => Array
                (
                    [sequence_number] => 2541
                    [date_of_reading] => 2018-03-16 11:41:47
                    [previous_billing_date] => 2018-03-13 10:26:05
                    [previous_reading] => 10000
                    [current_reading] => 12000
                    [water_charge] => 6.50
                    [supervisor_charge] => 0.00
                    [penalty] => 0.00
                    [meter_status] => ABNORMAL READING
                    [bill_no] => 843227171127296
                    [arrears] => 0.00
                    [total_amount] => 17.00
                    [total_unit_used] => 2000
                    [paid_amount] => 7
                    [payment_date] => 2018-03-06 00:00:00
                    [transaction_number] => 
                )


        )
```

Needed new array with field value(date of reading to transaction number ) from second array of same sequence number as separate array inside new array. Multidimensional array inside that array.

Comment: My assumption is `sequence_number` is your unique key? What is the source of this data? is it from a database?

Comment: yes sequence_number  is unique key and data is  from mysql database

Comment: If this is from mysql, then read into performing table Joins, much better to select it with a join then perform array translations in php. Again, with asking a question provide context, because I was certain you were going to say it is from a database. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/join.html

Comment: join is possible but data is required in this format as it is needed to display in a datatable

Answer (score 0):

You can merge array using [`array_merge()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) function

Answer (score 0):

This is a guess...

Nest array2 into array1 'children' index...

```
// index array 1 by sequence_number
$array1 = array_combine( array_column( $array1, 'sequence_number' ), $array1 );

foreach( $array2 as $two )
{
  if( !isset( $array1[ $two['sequence_number'] ]['children'] ) )
  {
    $array1[ $two['sequence_number'] ]['children'] = array();
  }
  $array1[ $two['sequence_number'] ]['children'][] = $two;
}
```